# prefetchRowsAt not called for last rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagination, uitableviewdatasourceprefetching

I am facing one issue in the **UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching** implementation.

I have 62 records total in the cloud and I am calling the API which returns 15 records per page.

I have implemented the **prefetchRowsAt** method as well which partially works fine for me.

The issue is the above method does not return all the indexPath it is going to load so as you can see from below logs it goes up to 53 only and in my table view it shows 60 records only.

```
Indexpaths to fetch : [[3, 51], [3, 42], [3, 52], [3, 41], [3, 53], [3, 40], [3, 54], [3, 39], [3, 55], [3, 38], [3, 56], [3, 37], [3, 57], [3, 36], [3, 58], [3, 35], [3, 59], [3, 34], [3, 60], [3, 33]]
Indexpaths to fetch : [[3, 51], [3, 50], [3, 49], [3, 48], [3, 47], [3, 46], [3, 45], [3, 44], [3, 43]]
Indexpaths to fetch : [[3, 52]]
Indexpaths to fetch : [[3, 53]]
```

Here is my method implementation

```
extension MyViewController:UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        #if DEBUG
            print("Indexpaths to fetch : \(indexPaths)")
        #endif

        if indexPaths.contains(where: isLoadingCell) {
            self.loadFurthersSessionNotification?()
        }
    }
}

private extension MyViewController {
  func isLoadingCell(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.section != 3{
        return false
    }
    return (indexPath.row - 1) >= self.aryCloudObjects.count
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing unexpected with the behaviour you are seeing.  There is no guarantee that `prefetchRowsAt` will be called for every row in your table.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching/1771764-tableview):

> Table views do not call this method for cells they require immediately, so your data source object must also be able to fetch the data itself.

Prefetching allows you to be prepared to display rows, but if the data hasn't been prefetched when `cellForRowAt:` is called then you need to fetch the data then.

Comment: Is there any other way you suggest for pagination then?

Comment: As per above answer, I can not rely on that I guess

Comment: The pre-fetch data source isn't for pagination; it simply allows you to fetch data (which may take some time) in advance of the cell being displayed.  Your pre-fetch data source should update your data model.  If `cellForRowAt:` finds that the data hasn't been pre-fetched then it needs to initiate the data fetch, as you would do without pre-fetching